# System.gc does not clears in a single run. Uses 3 or more calls for clearing

Tags: java, garbage-collection, visualvm

I am testing the usage of Heap size in a java application running in JDK 1.6. I use the tool VisualVM to monitor the heap usage. I found the Maximum heap size usage of around 500 MB for a few mins. I used the option "Perform GC" which calls System.gc(). The first time i used it, the Maximum heap is reduced to 410MB, then once again I used it to get 130MB and the next time to 85MB. I made all the four calls next to next without any interval. Why does the call System.gc() does not collect all the Heap to 85MB at first time. Is there any other reason behind this. Or I should try with any other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.gc() will return when all objects have been scanned once.

An object should be finalized() AFTER it has been collected.  Most objects don't implement this method but for the ones which do, they are added to a queue to be cleaned up later.  This means those objects cannot be cleaned up yet (not the queue nodes which hold them) i.e. the act of triggering a GC can *increase* memory consumption temporarily.

Additionally there are SoftReferences to objects which may or may not be cleaned up by a GC.  The assumption is these should only be cleaned up if not much else was cleaned up.

In short, not all objects can be cleaned up in one cycle.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there any way to force JVM to collect all objects for cleaning?

Comment: It does collect all the objects available at that time.  The problem is that some objects cannot be collected immediately.  There is  work which needs to be done aftre the object was collected and this does cannot be performed during a GC, so the answer is; what you want is impossible with the current implementation.  e.g. the finalizers cannot run while a full collection is being performed, and this in turn creates some garbage which is unavoidable in the general case.

Comment: Generally speaking you should minimise the use of finalisers and references.  If this is a problem, I would look at fixing the code so it doesn't use them so much.

Comment: The shorter answer, I wouldn't worry about a few hundred MB, I would just worry about GBs of memory.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() requests the JVM to start garbage collection. If you are expecting that GC is invoked as soon as System.gc() then it is a wrong notion. Calling it multiple times will not help. It is not possible to map System.gc() with the actual garbage collection. Also no matter how many times you call System.gc(), JVM will do the GC only when it is ready to do so. What may be happening is that heap size is getting reduced even with the first System.gc() but not exactly as soon as you call it. Garbage collection related to your first System.gc() may be finishing in background and in parallel your code is reaching third System.gc() statement.

If you are pretty sure that only adding multiple System.gc() helps you reducing the heap size. Then you need to check what all objects are getting created in JVM in between first and last System.gc(). There may be other threads creating the objects.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason might be the use of `java.lang.ref.Reference` types.  If the GC is going to break a "Reference" this will happen after the GC proper has completed.  Any objects that become unreachable as a result are left for the next GC cycle to deal with.

Finalization works the same way.  If an object requires finalization, it and all of the objects reachable from it (only) are likely to only be collectable in the next GC cycle.

Then there is the issue that the GC's algorithm for shrinking the heap is non-aggressive.  According to the [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) page, the GC only shrinks the heap if more than 70% is free after garbage collection.  However, it is not entirely clear if this refers to a full GC or not.  So you could get the GC doing a partial GC and shrinking, and then a full GC and shrinking some more.

(Some people infer from the wording of the `System.gc()` javadocs that it will perform a full GC.  However, I suspect that this is actually version / GC dependent.)

---

But to be honest this should all be moot.  Trying to coerce an application into giving back as much memory is possible is pointless.  The chances are that you are forcing it to throw away cached data.  When the application gets active again it will start reloading its caches.